# Unable to install Liferay Dev Studio CE bundled version

Tags: java, eclipse, liferay, liferay-theme, liferay-ide

Iam trying to install Liferay Dev Studio in my windows 7 system but its throwing me a error as below,

[image]

I have already installed jdk1.8.0_191 and it is available in the path as shown in the screenshot. I couldnt identify the issue here.

Downloaded the exe file "LiferayProjectSDKwithDevStudioCommunityEdition-2018.11.4-windows-installer.exe" from sourceforge from this [link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/lportal/files/Liferay%20IDE/3.4.0/).

I tried installing node jpm also, but that doesn't help. I like to create Liferay themes with the Dev Studio but Iam stuck.

Can any one help me to identify the issue. This issue is blocking my work.

Adding more information:

After clicking okay on the above dialog, Iam seeing the below dialog.
[image]

But I couldn't find Dev studio anywhere in the system.

Comment: Could you install blade manually afterwards? Please look at Preferences->Liferay->Blade->(Update or Restore). Also you mentioned the tag liferay-6 : But afaik you dont need Blade CLI to build liferay 6 themes

Comment: Thanks for responding. Iam using Liferay 7 only. I can install Blade manually but Liferay dev studio itself not installed because of this error. After clicking okay on the above dialog its saying that set up has finished installing but I couldn't find the dev studio anywhere in my system. I dono how to ignore blade while installing the dev studio as well. It will be verymuch helpful if you guide me on this.

Comment: Did you test to take a plain eclipse and install LiferayIDE using the Eclipse Marketplace. Please see [Liferay-IDE](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/liferay-ide)

Comment: Yes, that is how I finally installed it. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a quick workaround I installed eclipse JEE from this link: [link](https://community.liferay.com/project/-/asset_publisher/TyF2HQPLV1b5/content/ide-installation-instructions)

Then downloaded LiferaIDE (Liferay IDE 3.4.0 GA1 Archived Update-site) as a zip file and installed it to eclipse as a software package.
Link to download Liferay IDE 3.4.0 GA1 Archived Update-site:
[link](https://community.liferay.com/project/-/asset_publisher/TyF2HQPLV1b5/content/ide-installation-instructions)

This finally gave me the Liferay Dev studio setup.